# Quartz cron shedule is not triggered where expected to run every hour

Tags: java, cron, quartz-scheduler

The following expression is not triggered, but I expect it to be triggered every hour like 14:00, 15:00, 16:00

"0 0 0/1 * * ?"

Comment: And which times is it triggered instead? And are you sure, that you're problem is the cron and not the triggered program, which doesn't work for some reason?

Comment: I have just changed expression to "0 24 0/1 * * ?" and job was triggered at 15:24 (my local time), but original from my questions if not working

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to say, but Tom was right (many thanks to him) that there is some logic bug that made triggers to be paused, so some newly created jobs+triggers were working, but after some actions they became paused and any cron expression became useless. And after fixing this bug all the following expressions (I tried all of them while debugging) triggered job once per hour:

0 0 1/1 * * ?

0 0 0/1 1/1 * ?

0 0 0/1 * * ?

0 0 * * * ?

Comment: Mind that `0 0 1/1 * * ?` is a bit different, because it won't trigger at midnight. But glad to hear, that your bug is fixed and everything works like expected.

Answer (score 0):

To trigger daily use 1/1 in day part 0/1 the hour part to indicate every hour.
To start a cron anytime and to have it trigger every one hour the expression would look like:

> `0 0 0/1 1/1 * ? *`

I just tested and it shows dates and times for next few hundred hours.
You can generate your own [here](http://www.cronmaker.com/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: The `*` matches every day, so there is no need to change something there.

Comment: @Tom Besides my own code, I am following the cron maker as well. It only looks obvious to leave it as : `0 0 0/1 1/1 * * *` but cronmaker.com [link](http://www.cronmaker.com) outputs `0 0 0/1 1/1 * ? *` for the same criteria.

Comment: You can write the "same" cron in different variations. The version of the "cron maker" might not be wrong, but this won't fix OPs problem, because OPs cron isn't wrong either.

Comment: The thing is that I already checked my expression against cronmaker.com and it shows that expression is fine and should be executed once an hour as I expect, but in fact it doesn't

Comment: @Woworks Well, then the problem is not the cron itself, but something else, like the scheduler or the triggered job, which either doesn't work at some times or is already running and you set up the scheduler to not trigger a job, if it is already running.

Comment: @Tom I tried this expression in my code (0 0 0/1 1/1 * * * ) but got this error: `Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Support for specifying both a day-of-week AND a day-of-month parameter is not implemented.
 at org.quartz.CronExpression.buildExpression(CronExpression.java:511)` So what cronmaker.com outputs (as in my current and original answer) is correct for quartz version 2.2.1 jar.

Comment: And what do you want to tell me? As I said, the cron from "cronmaker.com" might not be wrong, but OPs cron isn't wrong, as well.

Comment: @Tom I'am checking validity of these expressions in my simple driver program. The one in my answer works as required( once every hour from the start of the program). Besides good theories do you suggest/have any definitive expression which can server to answer? Does the OP's expression even work in code? I can see that it does compile but it will take at least an hour to see any output, so the OP's expression doesn't serve from the beginning of the program, mine does.

Comment: *"Does the OP's expression even work in code?"* Yes it does. I tested it myself. *"I can see that it does compile but it will take at least an hour to see any output"* Then there is something wrong with your test program. The Cron fires at every full hour. If you start your program too late, like xx:00:10, then yes, you have to wait.

Comment: @Tom OP's expression doesn't work from the beginning of execution so, whatever job is scheduled won't start from start of execution. Mine works to run job from start of execution. Here is snippets for Trigger and the Scheduler in my code: `Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity("dummyTriggerName", "group1").withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0 0 0/1 * * ?")).build(); Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();scheduler.start();scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);` and it serves to execute job from beginning of execution of the program.

Comment: So the job gets triggered if the application starts? OP didn't that he wants that? His job is supposed to get triggered according to the cron (every full hour). He didn't said that he whats his cron to fire passed hour according to the application startup time.

Comment: @Woworks can you please update if anything worked out for you?

Comment: @Tom ..Can you please share any sample that would rule out any problem in cron expression? Do you have a solution?  Did you create a dummy job and schedule a dummy trigger? Did it fire every hour? Starting when? What would you suggest as an answer? Both OP's and mine expressions may hold, but which one would you suggest to choose and why?

Comment: OPs cron is correct, that is all I can say for now. Since OPs is really vague about his problem, his code and his expectations, there is nothing to say right now. *"Did you create a dummy job and schedule a dummy trigger?"* Neither, I just replaced the cron in a project which already uses quartz crons and works correctly. *"Starting when?"* the job was first triggered at the next full hour after program startup, like expected.

Comment: *"Both OP's and mine expressions may hold, but which one would you suggest to choose and why?"* Let's assume OPs  wants a cron which fires at every full hour on every day, then I would either use OPs cron or the cron of the other answer `0 0 * * * ?`. Reason: they are simple. If I have no rule for a certain part, then I prefer to just use a `*`, because it shows which part of the cron contains a restriction (in OPs case: only the seconds, the minutes and the hours are necessary to care about). But there is nothing generally wrong with using `1/1` instead of `*`.

Comment: @Tom you mentioned about using `0 0 0/1 1/1 * * * ` right? in the first comment? That did not compile. I commented with the error above. Your first comment generally makes sense but gives a compilation error. So, when I changed that to `0 0 0/1 1/1 * ? *` , as in my answer, no compilation error and shows execution of first hour's job as soon as the program starts executing and subsequent ones after every hour.

Comment: *"@Tom you mentioned about using 0 0 0/1 1/1 * * * right? in the first comment?"* No, that is not what I meant. I said, I don't see the point in using `1/1` instead of `*` to tell the cron should trigger on every day. I never said anything about the last place of the cron. So the cron you mean could be `0 0 0/1 1/1 * ?`, but I haven't tested this one. *" shows execution of first hour's job as soon as the program starts"* I might be wrong, but this happens due to the scheduler/trigger setting and has nothing to do with the cron itself.